# VBA Err.Raise function: "Continue" button grayed out

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm writing a large VBA program, and I'm trying to come up with a way to show the user an error that lets them know where in the code the error occurred. Using the built-in **Err.Raise** function generates a run-time error and shows it to the user, which allows them to click "Debug" and open the editor of course, but I would like to let them use the "Continue" button to keep running code, but it's grayed out:

[image]

Google and the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/raise-method) don't turn up any info. Does anyone know how to activate that Continue button, or am I stuck with creating my own handler that just shows the line number of the error?

Comment: How do you expect it to continue when there is an error? You are better off checking for the possibility of an error before it occurs and prevent it from erroring. If they need to see which line, all they need to do is click DEBUG.

Comment: @braX Maybe I should be more specific, this IS where I check for the possibility of an error. This would come up if the user uses the program on data that it is not designed to support, but the bad section can be skipped. I don't need the "continue" button for standard errors, just when I call Err.Raise -- basically as a fancier MsgBox with a "Debug" button. In that case, I need "Continue" to just be like the "Resume Next" statement

Comment: Would help to show the code you're using, and add a little more detail around what you expect the user to do with the code once you raise the error.   As @braX notes - there's no "Continue" without the user editing the code in some way.

Comment: @TimWilliams To clarify, I don't expect the user to do anything with the code in this case. I would imagine that the Continue button would act like the built-in "On Error Resume Next" statement and jump to the next line.

I would imagine that the existence of the "Continue" button implies that there's some way to use it--but VBA is a strange thing :)

Comment: I think you imagine incorrectly ?

Comment: @TimWilliams put another way, I would think that the "Continue" button would do the same thing as if the user clicked "Debug" and then "Debug -> Step Over" in the editor. But maybe it wasn't implemented

Comment: If I'm correct, @braX TimWilliams, you guys are saying that what I want to do--in the case of a run-time error, give the user the option to step to the next line and continue execution--isn't possible, correct? If so, I disagree--it is possible to be done both automatically ("On Error Resume Next") and by the user ("Debug" then "Debug"->"Step Over"). Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: "Continue: If code execution was suspended when the error occurred, clicking the Continue button will resume execution at the next line of code in the procedure. This option is disabled (not available) in most cases" You can get an active "continue" button by doing something like hitting Esc or Ctrl+Break during a long-running loop.

Comment: Just create an error handler. In the error handler is where you put the `Resume Next`, after a MsgBox prompt asking them if they want to continue, but it wont look like the normal error popup.

Comment: @braX Thanks guys. I learned a lot researching and thinking about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and with the help of @braX and @TimWilliams I think I'll just show a MsgBox instead of using Err.Raise. Thanks Guys!